# Remove line and previous comma from sql file using GREP

Tags: macos, terminal, grep

I am trying to turn this:

```
  KEY `vehicle_classification_id` (`vehicle_classification_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `BodyStyle_VehicleClassification` FOREIGN KEY 
(`vehicle_classification_id`) REFERENCES `vehicle_classifications` (`id`$
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

into this:

```
  KEY `vehicle_classification_id` (`vehicle_classification_id`)
(`vehicle_classification_id`) REFERENCES `vehicle_classifications` (`id`$
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

THIS SED AND GREP COMMAND REMOVE THE 'CONTRAINT' LINE, JUST NEED TO REMOVE THE COMMA FROM THE PREVIOUS LINE:

```
grep -vE ",*CONSTRAINT*" ~/Test.sql > ~/Stripped.sql
sed  -e 's/,*CONSTRAINT.*//' ~/Test.sql
```

If anyone knows how to do this with sed I would appreciate some guidance. Thank you.

Comment: From the `grep` manpage: "The grep utility searches any given input files, selecting lines that match one or more patterns."
On its own grep cannot be used to replace (partial) text - usually tools like `awk` or `sed` will be used for this kind of task. Are you able to use these in your environment?

Comment: I believe I can use sed, but have not tried awk. I will need to try and figure out equivalent command and patter match. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't get hung-up on the multi-line part (assuming that you have several similar blocks, you're not giving much sample data to work with):

```
echo '  KEY `vehicle_classification_id` (`vehicle_classification_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `BodyStyle_VehicleClassification` FOREIGN KEY 
(`vehicle_classification_id`) REFERENCES `vehicle_classifications` (`id`$
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;' | tr '\n' '\f' | sed  -e 's/,\f *CONSTRAINT[^\f]*\f/\f/'  | tr '\f' '\n'
  KEY `vehicle_classification_id` (`vehicle_classification_id`)
(`vehicle_classification_id`) REFERENCES `vehicle_classifications` (`id`$
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=29 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do have similar blocks but the file is massive. In short I want to only remove the previous comma on lines where the start of the line is 'CONSTRAINT'. I did try your command, but got this output: sed: illegal option -- r

Comment: What version of linux are you on, what is sed's version number?

Comment: Unfortunately it hasn't worked. It looks to me like the tr command is not replacing the new lines :/

Comment: Which brings me back to my previous question: what version of Linux are you using? @Paul

Comment: @Paul - are you on MacOS or and older BSD rather than Linux? Windows & cygwin?

Comment: I am use MacOS 10.12.6 for testing before using on Linux CentOS 6.9

Comment: Well ... you should update your tags, then. Or use homebrew provided tools on mac - otherwise you'll have potentially serious portability issues.  The toolset on the mac is geriatric, errrh, classic¸ and misses lots of extensions/improvements the GNU toolset on linux has.

Comment: This also raises the question how you created the original SQL file ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158889/discussion-between-paul-and-tink).

Answer (score 2):

**sed** approach:

```
sed '/\s*KEY /{ N; s/,\s*CONSTRAINT .*//}' ~/Test.sql > ~/Stripped.sql
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I got the response: sed: 1: "/\s*KEY /{ N; s/,\s*CON ...": bad flag in substitute command: '}'. Trying to resolve but please let me know if you have the answer.

Comment: @Paul, try to add semicolon after substituion command `'/\s*KEY /{ N; s/,\s*CONSTRAINT .*//; }'`

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I made the change and it did not return any error messages, but did not remove any lines from the file created.